# Using '>' in the command prompt will redirect output for one python script, but not for another

Tags: python, cmd

I currently have a python script called `tt.py` added to the Windows PATH variable so that I can run it from any directory. `tt.py` consists of the following files and functions:

- `tt.py`

  - `Concatenate.py`

    - `cat`
    - `tac`
  - `CutPaste.py`

    - `cut`
    - `paste`
  - `Grep.py`

    - `grep`
    - `startgrep`
  - `Partial.py`

    - `head`
    - `tail`

Each function is called via command-line arguments when running `tt.py`. I'm trying to process `file.csv` using `tt.py`, and when I run

```
tt.py head file.csv > outputfile.csv
```

It redirects the print statements from `head` to `outputfile.csv` as expected. However, when I run

```
tt.py startgrep <searchterm> file.csv > outputfile.csv
```

it simply prints to the console and treats `>` as an argument for the program. Both functions work as expected, I just don't understand how cmd will redirect properly for one case but not the other. What reasons are there why the `>` operator would not function consistently like this?

Comment: escape it using caret. `^<searchterm^>`

Comment: What is the exact `<searchterm>` you are using?